# Outputting console data from a process to gui in wxwidgets

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm running a long process in the background. I've managed to output the console data to gui. But the problem is that, the data is returned only after the process is finished. But I need to display the data at realtime. ie, I need to display the data, every time it produces some output on the console. I'm running the process with in my gui from a seperate thread.

I mean, it would be like building a gui for the ping command, where output is displayed on console after each packet is send, ie at realtime. I just need to redirect that to gui, in realtime. I'm implementing the gui in wxwidgets. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanking You..

Jvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the output you wish to display generated in a separate process from the process running the GUI?  Or in a separate thread in the same process?

I ask because most people, when they ask this question, mean a a separate thread.  Since you have tagged your question with "process" I will assume that is what you mean.

You need some inter-process communication.  There is a bewildering variety of techniques to do this.  Personally, I always use sockets.

wxWidgets has simple, easy to use socket classes wxSocketClient and wxSocketServer.

The background process is probably not running wxWidgets, so you will need something else there.  I reccomend boost::asio.  I know it looks intimidating, but in fact the tutorial code can be used as is.

There is a lot more to be said, but I risk straying away from the point, since there are so few details in your question.

Comment: I found a simple answer from http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks and it really works...

Answer (score 1):

You can have an output queue protected by a wxMutex. The thread doing the computation writes to the queue, then signals the GUI thread using wxQueueEvent with a custom event to let it know that the thread is not empty. The GUI thread then reads the queue and outputs the data.